# How to get called function name in __construct without debug_backtrace

Tags: php

How to get a caller method name in an class constructor, get_called_class() gives me the name of an extended class which was instantiated but how can I get the name of a method which was called in that class?
I need this for a production state so debug_backtrace() is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need this? If you have *any* consideration for other coders on the project and standards, find a solution which does *not* require the constructor to know about how it was called. If all other solutions fail, define a static factory method and make the constructor private for more control over instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the debug_backtrace() function, you can also throw and catch an exception, to get a backtrace.

But that's also ugly... Anyway:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    print_r( $e->getTrace() );
}
```

I don't know why you need the caller. Maybe you can fix this by using a different logic.
It should be better than getting a backtrace...

**EDIT**

The exception does not need to be thrown. Sorry for that part.
So you can simply use:

```
$e = new Exception();
print_r( $e->getTrace() );
```

**But once again, you shouldn't need to use this!**

Comment: Cant use simply use: `$e = new Exception; $e->getTrace()`? Is it required to be thrown, to get the trace?

Comment: I thought so, but I've just tested, and no, it does not need to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is not way to get it without `debug_backtrace()`. Still you can create your our function for this. Example from [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php#98909):

```
function get_caller_method() 
{ 
    $traces = debug_backtrace(); 

    if (isset($traces[2])) 
    { 
        return $traces[2]['function']; 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way of doing this other than the slow/ugly debug_backtrace, or passing the name as an argument to the constructor.... but you shouldn't really be building these kinds of dependencies into your classes.